# JDEE can not detect multi file

Tags: java

I have two files `A.java` (base class) and `B.java` (class). The class `B` succeed `A`. In file `B.java`, I compiled by `C-c C-v C-c`, then it can not detect file `A.java` with error message:

```
cannot find symbol
```

But it works well in compiling manually in terminal.

Also, when I try debugging in JDE, I only get:

```
cd: No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable in mini buffer.
```

I guess it is a path problem. I do not know how to fix this.